# In swift how to set CollectionView height according to its content while it is in the tableview cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

Hi I am creating an app where I need to show day and time , in which day are showing first in the table view cell and when click on table view cell the cell will expand and show the collection view , in this collection view I have list of time of that particular date. So my question is how to show these array of time in collection view so that I do not need to scroll , the height of collection view will increase according to its content.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use the UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout. It'll allow you to build very flexible width and height cells. It has a func called .estimated(estimatedDimension:) which will calculate it's point greater than or equal to the value you passed in.

Comment: Actually I want to increase the height of collection view according to how many cells are in there, not the size of cells.

Comment: I think it needs some calcuation like multiplying a row height with the number of rows and change the height constraint or frame.